# How to increase volume from cubic centimeter to a meter?

Tags: volume, unit-of-measure

I am trying to figure out how to calculate the change in concentration of an object within a volume, when you increase that volume. For example...

Let's say we have 5 flies per cubic centimetre of air.

Therefore, this would be 5,000,000 flies per cubic meter of air.

These are $5cm^{-3}$ and $5 \times 10^6m^{-3}$

Am I correct in my thinking? Also, how would I go on to figure how many flies there would be in say a km$^{-3}$ (cubic kilometer).

Comment: They would be small flies if you fitted 5 into a cc. Leaving that aside, yes, $1m=100cm$, so $1m^3=10^6cm^3$. 2nd part: $1km=10^3m$, so 1 cubic km = $10^9m^3$ etc. The only tricky part is the way the SI prefixes work: $1cm^3$ means $1cm\times1cm\times1cm$ not a hundredth of a cubic metre.

Comment: It looks fine. Go on.

Comment: Is there a tutorial / area of mathematics that walks through this? I am struggling to understand this intuitively/visually and would like a step by step answer/tutorial. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Using dimensional analysis:

$$\dfrac{5 \textrm{ flies}}{(1\textrm{cm})^3} * \dfrac{(1\textrm{cm})^3}{(10^{-2}\textrm{m})^3} = 5*10^{6} \textrm{ flies} \textrm{ m}^{-3},$$

which is valid because by definition $1 \textrm{ cm} = 1*10^{-2} \textrm{m}.$ Apply the same mentality to the second question, and you will be able to get the answer.

Comment: Following this mentality, would the amount of flies in a cubic kilometer be $5*10^{15} \textrm{ flies} \textrm{ m}^{-3}$?

Comment: Also, why does the cubic meter go from positive to negative, i.e. from ${ m}^{3}$ to ${ m}^{-3}$? Thanks

Comment: In response to the first question: no, the density per cubic meter is the same as above (I think you might have made a typo). The correct answer is that there are $5*10^{15} \textrm{flies} \textrm{ km}^{-3}.$

In response to the second question, the negative on the exponent simply indicates that the measurement is given per unit volume. When you say that there are a certain number of flies per centimeter cubed, you mean that the unit of the value will be $\dfrac{\textrm{flies}}{\textrm{ cm}^{-3}} = \textrm{flies} * \textrm{ cm}^{-3}.$ Does that make sense?